# Unmarshalling response throws casting errors (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.TextImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.soap.Node)

Tags: spring-boot

I've inherited an application written in Spring boot that takes handles incoming SOAP requests, encrypts them, and delivers them to an external endpoint. I had to upgrade the application from Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.1 and most of the functionality works. SOAP requests are received, encrypted, and sent out without issue but the application cannot unmarshal the response from the external endpoint. I consistently get the same error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.TextImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.soap.Node
(com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.TextImpl is in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap';
jakarta.xml.soap.Node is in unnamed module of loader 
org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @67424e82)
```

Messages initiated by external server are unmarshalled successfully which adds to my confusion.

I've tried rebuilding the classes from the WSDL and dug through the interceptors to see if I missed a configuration but this is the one case where the application runs into issues. Searches into the error tell me this is probably an issue with the marshaller.

Any suggestions on where to look next would be helpful.

Comment: Can you check out that the WSDL elements are being respected with the contents being sent? I remember a while back working with mule soft that a similar error happened and it was a "breach of contract" I search and found it again https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/NoClassDefFoundError-when-using-WSC-Consume
Not saying that it is the same but might worth checking.